EFK Data is getting lost on pod restart
I am facing the data persistence issue for EFK setup when pod gets restarted. I have setup the master, data and client pod.
Please have a look at below configurations.
master.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: infra
  name: elasticsearch-master
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
      role: master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
        role: master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch-master
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
        env:
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: NODE_NAME
          value: elasticsearch-master
        - name: NODE_LIST
          value: elasticsearch-master,elasticsearch-data,elasticsearch-client
        - name: MASTER_NODES
          value: elasticsearch-master
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
        - name: elastic-certificates
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: elasticsearch-master-config
      - name: elastic-certificates
        secret:
          secretName: elastic-certificates
      initContainers:
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
---

data.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: infra
  name: elasticsearch-data
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: data
spec:
  serviceName: "elasticsearch-data"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch-data
      role: data
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-data
        role: data
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch-data
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
        env:
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: NODE_NAME
          value: elasticsearch-data
        - name: NODE_LIST
          value: elasticsearch-master,elasticsearch-data,elasticsearch-client
        - name: MASTER_NODES
          value: elasticsearch-master
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms300m -Xmx300m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
        - name: elasticsearch-data-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - name: elastic-certificates
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: elasticsearch-data-config
      - name: elastic-certificates
        secret:
          secretName: elastic-certificates
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: [ "sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data" ]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-data-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: elasticsearch-data-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "gp2"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: standard
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
---

client.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: infra
  name: elasticsearch-client
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
      role: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
        role: client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch-client
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
        env:
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: NODE_NAME
          value: elasticsearch-client
        - name: NODE_LIST
          value: elasticsearch-master,elasticsearch-data,elasticsearch-client
        - name: MASTER_NODES
          value: elasticsearch-master
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: client
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
        - name: elastic-certificates
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: elasticsearch-client-config
      - name: elastic-certificates
        secret:
          secretName: elastic-certificates
      initContainers:
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
---

When pod get retarted, it gives the cluster UUID mismatch error.
The error message indicates that the Elasticsearch node is trying to join a cluster with a different UUID than the one it previously belonged to. This situation typically occurs when there are inconsistencies in the cluster configuration or data paths.

Tried adding persistaence volume to master pod and it gives error as data node is not able to identify the master.
Help will be really appriciated.

Here's a little script I (partly) wrote, that will help you fix the issue:
#!/bin/bash

# Create a persistent volume claim (PVC) for the data node
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
EOF

# Update the data node configuration to use the PVC
kubectl patch statefulset elasticsearch-data -p='{"spec":{"volumeClaimTemplates":[{"metadata":{"name":"elasticsearch-data-persistent-storage"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"50Gi"}}}}]}}'

# Verify the data node configuration
kubectl get statefulset elasticsearch-data -o yaml

# Verify the PVC status
kubectl get pvc elasticsearch-data-pvc -o yaml

It creates a persistent volume claim for the data node, then updates the data node config to use the PVC, and then verifies the configuration and PVC status.
You have to run this scritp in the correct namespace (infra in your case,) and adjust the storage and access modes according to your soecific requirements.
Please be very aware that this script is just a suggestion, and I haven’t tested it, so you should test it in a non-production environment before applying it to your production cluster.
